# Parse.com LEFT JOIN alternative

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, nosql

Can someone please explain what the correct data structure would be in a noSQL environment like parse.com to do the equivalent of a LEFT JOIN in SQL. I come from a relational world so I am very much open to the idea that my tables need to be entirely redesigned.

I want to store "Jobs" and "Users" where Users can post Jobs and Apply to Jobs. So I created three tables: "Job", "User", and "Application". Applications has three columns: "pointer to Job", "pointer to User", and "Application status".

Problem is:

1. I can't in single query get all the jobs posted by a user with the number of applications for each.
2. I can't in a single query get all available job for a user and also know whether that user applied

   I am using parse.com for this project.

**EDIT for bounty**

I have several solutions with either multiple queries or using arrays in the Job table. Each has limitations but I am looking to understand if there is a better data structure or query to get all jobs with the applications for those jobs.

Comment: NoSQL refers to a broad range of technologies that store and process data.  Can you be more specific about which database you are using, and tag the question appropriately?

Comment: Using parse.com for this project. I will amend the questions.

Comment: I tagged the question javascript to cause the answer to properly syntax highlight.  There's a way to do this in answer markup, but I couldn't get that to work.  Let me know if this is the parse sdk you're using, otherwise feel free to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second answer in brief: taking the question constraints strictly (given data model, one query, given output), I think the problem is over constrained.  We can achieve the functional goal by relaxing either the fixed data model or the single query.

First, **relaxing single query**.  My answer above I assumed the following data model...

```
Application --1 User (applicant)
          |
          --1 Job --1 User (postingUser)
```

...and suggested *a single* query of Application where the app job matched a Job via a second *implicit inner query*.  This idea solved most of the problem, but misses Jobs for which there are no applications (INNER JOIN, as you point out).

Repairing that error, we could achieve the goal with two *explicit* queries as follows:

```
var user = // a given user
var jobQuery = new Parse.Query("Job");
jobQuery.equalTo("postingUser", user);
var jobs = [];
jobQuery.find().then(function(results) {
    // requirement 1: jobs posted by a user
    jobs = results;
    var appQuery = new Parse.Query("Application");
    appQuery.containedIn("job", jobs);
    return appQuery.find();
}).then(function(apps) {
    _.each(jobs, function(job) {
        // requirement 1.1: jobs' related to apps (trivial to count them)
        job["applications"] = _.find(apps, function(app) {
            return app.get("job").id == job.id;
        });

        // requirement 2: decorate jobs where the postingUser is an applicant
        // could have combined loops above, but looping again for clarity
        _.each(jobs, function(job) {
            var posterIsApplicant = _.find(apps, function(app) {
                return app.get("applicant").id == user.id
            });
            job["posterIsApplicant"] = app.get("user").id == user.id;
        });            
    });
});
```

Alternatively, **unconstrained by the data model**, but with a single query, we can get the functional result by arranging the data this way:

```
Job --1 User (postingUser)
   |
   --< Application (applications) --1 User (postingUser)
```

Here, Job has a pointer to user and an array of pointers (or a relation if you expect the cardinality to be high... my rule of thumb is > 100) to Application.  Application could continue to have a single pointer to Job if it was needed elsewhere (this could be maintained in beforeSave cloud code).

With that, its simple to achieve the function with a single query:

```
var user = // a given user
var jobQuery = new Parse.Query("Job");
jobQuery.equalTo("postingUser", user);
jobQuery.include("applications")l
jobQuery.find().then(function(results) {
    // requirement 1: results contains jobs, each has an array
    // of applications
    // requirement 2: is copy-paste from above
    _.each(results, function(job) {
        var apps = job.get("applications");
        var posterIsApplicant = _.find(apps, function(app) {
            return app.get("applicant").id == user.id
        });
        job["posterIsApplicant"] = app.get("user").id == user.id;
    });            
});
```

Comment: I completely agree with your answer. In fact I already coded the first version. I was just wondering if there was a way not to relax the constraints but I guess not. Thanks for the two excellent responses.

Answer (score 2):

It is doable.  Some things are more easily doable if you allow for a small number of queries as opposed to only one.  But I think your particular questions can be done with one query, if you allow for a little in-memory manipulation of the result.

```
// 1. assume that Job contains a pointer to the user who posted it (postingUser)
// 2. assume that Application's user column means the user who applied
// 3. Assume Javascript, though the sdk contains functional equivalents for several languages

var user = // a given user
var jobQuery = new Parse.Query("Job");
jobQuery.equalTo("postingUser", user);
// if you wanted all the jobs posted by user, we'd be ready to go
// but you also want application counts, which forces us to be more roundabout...
var appQuery = new Parse.Query("Application");
appQuery.matchesQuery("job", jobQuery);  // this is the nearest idea to LEFT JOIN
appQuery.include("job");  // eagerly fetch the related job

appQuery.find().then(function(applications) {
    // applications are applications for jobs posted by user
    // so here's the little in-memory work to get jobs (using underscorejs)
    var jobs = [];
    var appCounts = {};
    _.each(applications, function(app) {
        var job = app.get("job");  // remember job was eagerly fetched
        jobs.push(job);
        appCounts[job] = (appCounts[job])? appCounts[job]+1 : 1;

        // Taking your second question to mean "is the user who
        // posted the job also one of its applicants?"
        job["posterIsApplicant"] = app.get("user").id == user.id;
    });
});
```

When the above completes, `jobs` will contain the jobs posted by `user`, `appCounts[job]` will be the number of applications for any job, and `job["posterIsApplicant"]` will be true only if one of the applicants to that job is also the user that posted it.

Comment: So I finally got to this. Unless I am missing something, I think that what you are giving me an INNER JOIN as opposed to a LEFT JOIN. I need all jobs from user and Applications to those jobs. What you are giving me is only Jobs from user that have an application.

Comment: I see.  Hmm, I think we'll either need to do two queries, or (probably the right no-sql way) model the relationship from Job to Application with either a relation or an array of pointers.